# Azure Bot Service code update with continues developmemt

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

We had set up a bot service with LUIS in c#  for a few months, now on we want to enable continues development with VSTS. we had set up the project in VSTS and commit the source without problem. And the bot service is configured with VSTS and able to deploy successfully without errors. But we found the bot still operating with sample code logic and the code still a sample code in the build tab. Is it any solution to let the bot service replace the old sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend using the [SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart) over Azure Bot Service, but that is a personal preference.  I say this because it feels much like any project in Visual Studio and there are fewer steps to set up continuous deployment and other things like debugging locally.

For Azure Bot Service [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure-bot-service-continuous-deployment)  please read through this link to get started and make sure you did not miss a step.  There are also instructions to [debug your bot locally here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure-bot-service-debug-bot).  I hope this helps, please let me know if it does not.